# android datepicker using spinner

Tags: android

I tried to make spinner a date picker but it had no response on clicking on it. I want a code of a date picker in android which uses spinner that when we click on spinner it should display a date picker and  could set the date

Comment: Hello apps and welcome to SO! I would like to advise you some SO documentation that may help you in asking a better qestion. For instance you may be interested about the [topics we discuss here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [the way to ask a 'good' question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the way to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you find it useful, you can still edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, I am a *bit late* but anyone else who is having similar problem can refer to this approach.

After implementing, DatePicker in the xml

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

In the MainActivity.java ,

```
DatePicker datePicker = (findViewById(R.id.date_picker));
    datePicker.setOnDateChangedListener(new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String currentDate = (monthOfYear+1) + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;
            dateTextView.setText(currentDate);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Button instead of spinner, it will be more effective to pick and display date.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button datebutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    datebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

public void bottonclicked(View view){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            datebutton.setText(dateFormat.format(c1.getTime()));

            /* DateFormat datefmt= DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);  // to get date format in Feb 31,3017
                datebutton.setText(datefmt.format(c1.getTime())); */
        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(now);// To Disable previous dates and enables from present date in datepicker
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now+31536000000L);// for 365 days  1000*60*60*24*365  mill_sec*sec*min*hours*days
}
```